# Mapping from dynamic to type with property defined with interface type

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, automapper

The context around this is that I'd like to map a `dynamic` dapper result to an object and that object has a property which has an interface type:

```
public class TargetModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IAddress AbstractAddress { get; set; }
}
```

The dynamic to object bit is straight forward but I'm unable to configure AutoMapper to tell it how to handle the interface.

```
dynamic sourceModel = new ExpandoObject();

// flat model - id should map to TargetModel, Address01 will map to a nested type Address on TargetModel
sourceModel.Id = 1;
sourceModel.Address01 = "address01";

// for debugging purposes address maps ok from dynamic
Address address = Mapper.Map<Address>(sourceModel);

// this maps, but AbstractAddress is null - I need to config AutoMapper to understand how to map IAddress to Address
TargetModel target = Mapper.Map<TargetModel>(sourceModel);
```

I've tried to tell it how to deal with the property:

```
CreateMap<ExpandoObject, TargetModel>()
    .ForMember(y => y.AbstractAddress, opts => opts.MapFrom(f => f));
```

Which fails with:

> System.ArgumentException: Cannot create an instance of interface type

So I attempt to hint at the concrete:

```
CreateMap<IAddress, Address>().As<Address>();
```

Which doesn't resolve the issue and the exception remains.

I've looked at the following questions/concepts and tried various configuration options but haven't been able to get the map working:

- [AutoMapper: Mapping objects with interface properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760779/automapper-mapping-objects-with-interface-properties)
- https://dotnetfiddle.net/fPQxWx

Comment: "Doesn't know how to handle" and "goes pear" are ambiguous problem descriptions. Can you please tell us the specific problem? E.g. compilation or run time error, data not copied, data copied incorrectly, etc.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Comment: @JohnWu updated to be more specific.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I can see it maps the dynamic with no config/hints but I don't know how to ensure the property with interface is mapped.

Comment: You need to create a map from string to IAddress. By default AM will create a proxy, but if you need Address instead, you must tell AM that with As.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu would you be able to explain with an example? Here's a fiddle with an elaborate example https://dotnetfiddle.net/FWclT8.

Comment: I'm sure a little research goes a long way here.

Answer (score 1):

This is trying to map from a `string` in the `ExpandoObject` to an `IAddress` in your target type. Obviously it can't create an instance of `IAddress` to fill so you have to fulfill that yourself in the mapping.

If your models look like this:

```
public class TargetModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IAddress AbstractAddress { get; set; }
}

public interface IAddress
{
    string Address01 { get; set; }
}

public class Address : IAddress
{
    public string Address01 { get; set; }
}
```

Then your config and setup can look like this:

```
public void MappingTests()
{
    dynamic sourceModel = new ExpandoObject();

    // flat model - id should map to TargetModel, Address01 will map to a nested type Address on TargetModel
    sourceModel.Id = 1;
    sourceModel.Address01 = "address01";

    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<ExpandoObject, TargetModel>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.AbstractAddress, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new Address() { Address01 = src.First(kvp => kvp.Key == "Address01").Value.ToString() }))
        .ForMember(destinationMember => destinationMember.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.First(kvp => kvp.Key == "Id").Value));
    });

    TargetModel target = Mapper.Map<TargetModel>(sourceModel);
}
```

I just used it as an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`, but you can also treat the expando object like a dictionary by casting.

```
cfg.CreateMap<ExpandoObject, TargetModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.AbstractAddress, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new Address() { Address01 = ((IDictionary<string, object>)src)["Address01"].ToString() }))
    .ForMember(destinationMember => destinationMember.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => ((IDictionary<string, object>)src)["Id"]));
```

Comment: It's quite explicit, and not far off simply new'ing up the objects and setting the properties manually - does AutoMapper not have a built in way to map these without explicitly setting the properties via config?

Comment: I agree, it's not nice. But that's the only way I know of. Maybe there's something better out there, hopefully